# Is it possible to replace a char by another with CSS?

Tags: html, css, fonts

My goal is to replace the **display** of `_` by a **blank space** in my HTML document:

ex:

```
hello_world
```

should be

```
hello world
```

Possible Solutions:

Would be to create a

1. FONT that uses blank inside the _ character
2. Still looking for it!

Can this be done with CSS?

It is important that we do not modify the original string (we keep the _ character), but we simply display a **blank space** instead.

Regards

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: Your solution 1 seems just fine it you wish to keep the _ character, just not show it. CSS alone can't help you much there.

Comment: I guess you can use JS, but I think JS will change the content and not the display !

Comment: Simple answer...no. Font unicode-range adjustment maybe but that's nuking from orbit to crack a nut.

Comment: What's the motivation?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is possible in CSS for a one-off kind of thing:

```
<span class="replace-me">hello_world</span>


.replace-me{
    display:none;
}
.replace-me:after{
    content:'hello world';
}
```

But I'm guessing that's not exactly what you want.

Otherwise, to replace all instances in JS:

```
document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('_', ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely have to get a little more fancy with the regex but you could parse the page for underscores and wrap them in a `<span>`. Then use a pseudo element that has it's content set to a single space to replace the wrapped underscore.

```html
<p>
    Some_content with_underscores_going_on.
</p>
```

```css
span:after {
    font-size: 16px;
    content: ' ';
}
span {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

```js
// jQuery
var f = $("body"); 
f.html( f.html().replace(/_/g,"<span>_</span>") );
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/h2h1bmyn/1/